# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio connection logs

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller, ssms

I have a MVC application running  in the .NET framework on my local IIS, within the app I'm trying to connect to a sql database in SSMS, I get the error 'Access Denied'.

Is there a way to see what user accounts are trying to access the database?

Comment: Typically you would need to use some kind of credentials either it be a windows user account or sql server user account, if you have access to the code of the MVC application, you should be able to see what account it is using to make the connection to SSMS

Comment: I'm using the windows account to connect to the database from IIS.

Comment: Then you need to connect to SSMS and grant your windows account access to the database which you need to connect to.

Comment: so in that case either the account to be used is configured in IIS, in the settings of the Application Pool to which the website belongs, or, if you're using passthrough authentication then it will be the account of the user who is using the website. That windows user account, whatever it is, will need to be granted suitable access to the SQL Server

Comment: I have granted permissions to my account, my machine and it still dosnt let me through, I can see what the error is being thrown, but I need to know which account it is using.

Comment: Try using SQL Profiler. You have the ability to filter out events to only the ones you want, such as logins or grab all events if you don't know which one you'll need. It should be accessible under Tools | Sql Profiler in SSMS

Comment: Ah yes this works perfectly, thanks! The issue with access was fixed by simple switching the browser to Internet Explorer from Edge though haha

Comment: IIS runs apps in it's own process with it's own account. You need to find what user your IIS is running as. Probably something like "IIS_IUSRS"